# Frequent IOExceptions when iteratively writing or deleting files in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, file

We've inherited a batch job that translates data for about 50K people per instance. To simplify the problem, the way it works is for every person it processes, it generates 3 files:

> FileA.txt FileB.txt FileC.txt

Once the job has finished creating those 3 files, it consolidates their contents into a final Output.txt file. After it's done copying the contents of all 3 files, it deletes them, and then creates them anew for the next person. The logic to produce the contents of each file vary significantly from one another and is probably why it's been programmed such that each file is processed in their own respective class. As far as the creation and deletion of these files are concerned, there's nothing fancy, just basic File.Create and File.Delete.

This has been used for years, and has been generating the final Output.txt timely. However, after we transitioned to using this job from our on-prem server and into Azure, we're now stumbling to this issue where we randomly get an IO Exception on any of those 3 files as the job is trying to create it again for the next person. Debugging suggests that the code seem to think that the prior copy of the file still exists even though it went through File.Delete(x) without issues. We have already experimented with using different paths, from C:, D:, F:, Path.TempPath, to network shares, but still encounter the issue. The only workaround that seemed to have worked is to employ this while loop prior to attempting to create any of the 3 files anew:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(extractFilePath);

        while (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            fileInfo.Refresh();
        }
```

This works, but obviously nowhere near desirable. Certainly one route we can take is decompile and refactor the code so that it bypasses the creation / deletion of these files and go straight to that final Output.txt, but being that this has been working for years without any change, it's been difficult to get the work signed off.

All that being said, hoping to try and better understand what could be causing this after migrating to Azure. Tried to check via Process Explorer and saw MsMpEng.exe accessing the files while the job is running, but nothing definitive to suggest that it is in fact what's making the job think that a deleted file still exists and thus throw an IO Exception in attempts to create them.

Comment: Any reason not to just use `new FileStream` along with `FileMode.Create` which would just overwrite it?

Comment: That is an option if we get approval to refactor the code. That approval has been hard to come by, and we're being pressed to try and understand what config / setup after moving to Azure may be causing it.